# achieve send file in php chat like facebook chat

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, facebook

I have a chat and i would want to send files also during chat. I would want the same approach like facebook has: when you put the file it should not put into the specific textbox that comes with `input=file` and to not have the browse button? is this doable?

```
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input name="message" type="text" id="textb" value="" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Chat" id="post_button"/>
<input type="file" name="fisier">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's done with a combination of CSS and javascript.

Take a look at: http://www.dropzonejs.com/